# React this.state is null

Tags: reactjs, api

I try to do weather app in react, but when I add `${this.state.latitude}` in my const API I replaced null.
But when I try display `this.state.latitude` in `render()` I have a value.
What is wrong?

```
export class TodayWeather extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            latitude: "",
            longitude: "",
        };
    }

    getMyLocation =() => {
        const location = navigator.geolocation;
        if (location) {
            location.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
                this.setState({
                    latitude: position.coords.latitude,
                    longitude: position.coords.longitude,
                })
            },)}
    };

    getWeather = () => {
        this.getMyLocation();

        const API = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=${this.state.latitude}&lon=139&appid=${apiKey}`;

        fetch(API)
            .then(response => {
                if (response.ok) {
                    return response
                }
                throw Error("")
            })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                const time = new Date().toLocaleString();
                this.setState({
                })
            })})
    };
    componentDidMount() {
        this.getWeather();
    }
    render(){
            return (
            <div className="App">
                <Result className="result" weather={this.state}/>
                <p> {this.state.latitude} </p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: why are you setting state like this `this.setState({})`? It should not be empty object

Comment: @AlexandrZavalii How should it be correct?

Comment: Please remove the extra `})` right after `this.setState({})` in `getWeather` class method.

Comment: Furthermore, what are you aiming to `setState` in the `getWeather` method, when the fetch is done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expected order of execution is:

1. `this.getMyLocation()` which sets the `latitude` and `longitude` to state.
2. `this.getWeather()` which uses the state variable to make a xhr request (which is again async).

`this.setState` is *also* asynchronous. So by the time the state variables are set, `this.getWeather()` already starts executing, so it comes back null and the fetch request fails. So when the state variable is set, it triggers a rerender, which is why it does come in the `render`.

The solution to this is using a callback in the `setState`. I have made some minor modifications.

I called `this.getMyLocation()` on `componentDidMount`:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getMyLocation();
  }
```

In which I make use of the callback and invoke the modified `this.getWeather`:

```
this.setState(
          {
            latitude: position.coords.latitude,
            longitude: position.coords.longitude
          },
          this.getWeather
);
```

Where it no longer invokes `this.getMyLocation()` at its start.

Besides this, one obvious flaw is that you are not passing anything to the `setState` after the fetch is done, presumably the json data you obtain.

```
      .then((data) => {
        const time = new Date().toLocaleString();
        this.setState({
          // Something needs to come here, possibly:
          data
        });
      });
```

The full code:

```
export default class TodayWeather extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      latitude: '',
      longitude: ''
    };
  }

  getMyLocation = () => {
    const location = navigator.geolocation;
    if (location) {
      location.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
        this.setState(
          {
            latitude: position.coords.latitude,
            longitude: position.coords.longitude
          },
          this.getWeather
        );
      });
    }
  };

  getWeather = () => {
    const API = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=${
      this.state.latitude
    }&lon=139&appid=${apiKey}`;

    fetch(API)
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.ok) {
          return response;
        }
        throw Error('');
      })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        const time = new Date().toLocaleString();
        this.setState({
          // Something needs to come here
          data
        });
      });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getMyLocation();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Result className="result" weather={this.state} />
        <p> {this.state.latitude} </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: @ElaNescaffe Consider upvoting and accepting the answer if it solved the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

try this.. but the code looks very messy

```
export default class TodayWeather extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      latitude: '',
      longitude: ''
    };
  }

  getMyLocation = (getData) => {
    const location = navigator.geolocation;
    if (location) {
      location.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
        getData(position);
      });
    }
  };

  getWeather = () => {
    const getData = (position) => {
      this.setState({
        latitude: position.coords.latitude,
        longitude: position.coords.longitude
      });

      const API = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=${
        position.coords.latitude
      }&lon=139&appid=${apiKey}`;

      fetch(API)
        .then((response) => {
          if (response.ok) {
            return response;
          }
          throw Error('');
        })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
          const time = new Date().toLocaleString();
          this.setState({ time });
        });
    };

    this.getMyLocation(getData);
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getWeather();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Result className="result" weather={this.state} />
        <p> {this.state.latitude} </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```